# Navigation bar cross browser compatibility

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, navigationbar

I ran into an issue with cross-browser code.

I have added a floating navigation bar at the top of my page with the following code:

```
    <header id="page-header" class="content-info" role="contentinfo">
        <!-- Nav -->
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="1.html">1</a></li>
                <li><span>2</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="2.1.html">2.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="2.2.html">2.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="2.3.html">2.3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="2.4.html">2.4</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                <li><a href="3.html">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="4.html">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="5.html">5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

With the next css code:

```
header#page-header {
z-index: 9999;
position: fixed;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
top: 0;
right: 0;
background: white;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 2px;
color: #5b5b5b;
display: inline-table;
}
```

It works perfectly on all of the browsers except for IE. The navigation menu does not show up and it is because of the parameter "right: 0;". I have tried removing this parameter but then on browsers Chrome and Safari the menu is shifted half way to the right of the page.

I have tried creating a style for all browsers but the IE like follows:

```
<!--[if !IE]>< -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/xbrowser.css" />
<!-- ><![endif]-->
```

xbrowser.css file containing:

```
header#page-header {
right: 0;
}
```

I have made sure to remove the parameter "right: 0;" from the main css file. This did not work as IE still recognized the css file that I told it to ignore.

Can someone suggests a workaround to get this feature to work on all browsers ie Chrome, Safari, Opera, Mozilla and IE?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See example here http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html it looks like your brackets around the comment are wrong

Comment: Any suggestion on the issue with the navigation bar itself?

Comment: @MatthewLock I've tried different brackets as many sites suggest different and nothing worked.

Comment: Put it in jsfiddle so we can see it all running.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GJuN3/embedded/result/

Answer (score 2):

you need to alter your conditional comment, all browsers can currently still read it:

```
<!--[if ie]>
    Stuff. Only IE will read what's in here (up till IE 10)
<![end if]-->
```

In most cases, it'll be IE that needs the special treatment! Here's a good guide on [IE conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), they're very handy.

As for the navbar issue, as long as your IE-only CSS appears *after* the main css files, all you need to do is overwrite the offending property, in your case, `right:0;`

If it still doesn't appear to be working, I find it helps to test the conditional comments on their own to ensure they're working before dismissing the idea. Try putting something like this in plain sight on your HTML page:

```
<!--[if ie]>
    <h1>Conditional comments working in IE!</h1>
<!--[end if]>
```

Comment: @yury, did you try an obvious test to ensure the conditional comments are definitely working? I altered my answer to include one. If you add that and see the heading in IE, then you know the problem may lie in the CSS...

Comment: your `nav` is absolutely positioned inside the parent container, that will conflict with the `position:fixed` of the wrapper

Comment: why would it conflict? position for nav is set to absolute and it just overrides.

Comment: it appears to when I inspected it in IE9 for some reason. The developer console on IE9 isn't very friendly, but when I switched it off, the nav bar became visible again.

Applying `position:absolute` will indeed override the inherited `position:fixed` of the wrapper, making it unnecessary. Why position the wrapper like that only to remove the contents with `position:absolute`?

Comment: Your comment made me think in the right direction and I've re-written the code a bit for the navigation, removing higher elements and separating nav from header. It works now. Thanks